# Prevent system Keyboard from showing when TextInput is pressed in react native

Tags: react-native, keyboard, textinput

I want to show my custom keyboard component when an input field is press. I want to prevent the system default keyboard from getting triggered at all.

I have tried dismissing the keyboard on onFocus but this triggers the keyboard and then dismisses the keyboard.

```
 <TextInput
     placeholder="type here"
     onFocus={Keyboard.dismiss}
 />
```

I have tired wrapping the TextInput inside TouchableWithoutFeedback but this solution doesn't work.

```
<TouchableWithoutFeedback
    onPress={() => Keyboard.dismiss()}
    accessible={false}
>
    <View>
        <TextInput placeholder="type here" />
    </View>
</TouchableWithoutFeedback>
```

Any ideas how can I achieve the desired results?

Comment: You don't necessarily have to use a `TextInput` for that. You could just put a `Text` inside `TouchableWithoutFeedback` which triggers the keyboard, save your custom keyboard input in a state or something and then pass the value to `Text`

Comment: I thought of that idea but  `Text` component won't behave like `TextInput`.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can use `showSoftInputOnFocus` on Android, see the docs:
https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/textinput#showsoftinputonfocus

Your case is the same as avoiding showing the keyboard when an external keyboard is connected (on iPad it common).

Comment: This is exactly what I needed. Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 5):

Open AndroidManifest file in (android > app > src > main) folder of your project and then add :

```
android:windowSoftInputMode="stateHidden"
```

to your activity tag like this :

```
<activity
    android:name=".MainActivity"
    android:label="@string/app_name"
    android:configChanges="keyboard|keyboardHidden|orientation|screenSize"
    android:windowSoftInputMode="stateHidden">
```

Comment: android:windowSoftInputMode="stateHidden" still triggers the keyboard.

Comment: You can refer to this link : https://reactnativecode.com/manually-hide-soft-keyboard/